# Objectify: Get list of Strings NOT EQUAL to provided value

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I need to get the list of items whose `datePublished IS NOT ""`. However, the code below doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks

```
Query<Diagram> q=ofy.query(Diagram.class).filter("datePublished !=", "").order("-likes").limit(18);
```

Comment: Perhaps, you may try to use [partial index](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Partial_Indexes). e.g. `@Unindexed(IfEmptyString.class) String datePublished`

Answer (score 4):

When applying an inequality filter in the GAE datastore there are some restrictions.
You can read more here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries

In this case, to have an inequality on datePublished you must order on that same field primarily before you can order on another.

So assuming the datePublished field is indexed:

```
Query<Diagram> q=ofy.query(Diagram.class).filter("datePublished !=", "").order("datePublished").order("-likes").limit(18);
```

Assuming this isn't a migration concern, you may want to consider denormalising this data when you store it, for example setting a 'noDatePublished' boolean.